# Grafana variable to reference part of prometheus stat name

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is it possible to reference a prometheus metric by partially using a Grafana variable?

I have metrics coming in from multiple sources like this

foo_bar{job, status}
zoo_bar{job, status}
xoo_bar{job, status}

I have added an interval variable with a list of possible prefixes foo, zoo, xoo.
How do I reference the stats if I want to combine charts on one dashboard?
I tried something like this, but it gives me syntax error at the $ sign.

```
    increase(${var_name}_bar{job="myjob", status!~="401|404|500"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer for anybody potentially having the same issue.
Seems like moving the metric stats in side the curly brackets and referencing **name** works. If there is a a better solution I would be happy to know.

```
    increase({__name__=~"${variable}_bar", job="myjob", status!~="401|404|500"})
```

Comment: I think that's exactly how it should be done, however it would be better to have the `$variable` as a label in the first place, if you can control this part.